# How to make a basic ebook with chapters

Tags: creation

Basically, what I want to do is download one of the online textbooks I use for school (already dealt with) with each page as a .txt file so I can read my textbook on my e-reader instead of my computer. Anyway, so I couldn't find any good tutorials/I didn't know what to look for on how to make a basic ebook which consists of plain text and chapters so that's why I'm here!

TL;DR: I want to make a basic ebook with each page as simple text and with chapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/index.html) can convert from and to a large number of formats:

- It can read plain **text**, Markdown, CommonMark, PHP Markdown Extra, GitHub-Flavored Markdown, MultiMarkdown, and (subsets of) Textile, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, MediaWiki markup, TWiki markup, Haddock markup, OPML, Emacs Org mode, DocBook, txt2tags, EPUB, ODT and Word docx
- it can write plain text, Markdown, CommonMark, PHP Markdown Extra, GitHub-Flavored Markdown, MultiMarkdown, reStructuredText, XHTML, HTML5, LaTeX (including beamer slide shows), ConTeXt, RTF, OPML, DocBook, OpenDocument, ODT, Word docx, GNU Texinfo, MediaWiki markup, DokuWiki markup, ZimWiki markup, Haddock markup, **EPUB (v2 or v3)**, FictionBook2, Textile, groff man pages, Emacs Org mode, AsciiDoc, InDesign ICML, TEI Simple, and Slidy, Slideous, DZSlides, reveal.js or S5 HTML slide shows. It can also produce PDF output on systems where LaTeX, ConTeXt, or wkhtmltopdf is installed.
- It can create epub files with **chapters** *see [here](http://pandoc.org/epub.html) for instructions*.
- It runs on Linux, Windows & OS-X
- It is **free**, gratis & open source
- You can even point it at a URL and it will do a reasonable job of converting the online resource into an epub.

If are ready to take a little more time on preparation then the python [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) document generator can produce EPUB format, organised into chapters, from a number of input formats, including plain text.

- Also free, gratis & open source

Comment: Thanks, it works great and the fact that it's command line is terrific, it allows me to integrate it and do another step automatically!